# Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 3: No module named hairTools

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to run a script and this error came up,

```
Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 3: No module named hairTools
```

I'm really new to python scripts or scripts of any kind for that matter so I have no idea how to fix this. The script shows up on my custom application bar and a window pops up when I click on the link with everything looking good, but when I try to use the script the error shows up and nothing happens. I really appreciate any help I can get.

Here is my script

```
"""
------------------------------------------
hairTools.py
Author: David Bokser
email: me@davidbokser.com

Website : http://www.davidbokser.com
------------------------------------------

Helps create multi-level hair curves along a poly mesh, with tools
for styling and trimming.

Usage:
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
hairTools.hairballUI()

COPYRIGHT DAVID BOKSER 2010-2013.
================================================================
"""

_version = '1.5'

import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.mel as mel
import copy
import random

def hairballUI():
    window = mc.window( title="Hairball v%s" % _version, iconName='hairball', widthHeight=(200, 55) )

    mc.scrollLayout( 'scrollLayout' )
    mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    mc.button(label='Reload', command='''
import maya.cmds as mc
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
mc.deleteUI( "%s", window=True)
hairTools.hairballUI()
''' % window)
    mc.frameLayout( label='Grow', labelAlign='center', borderStyle='etchedIn' )
    mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )    
    densityField = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Density', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .4, fs=.01, minValue=.01, maxValue=1.0, fmx=200.0 )
    layerField = mc.intSliderGrp( label='Layers', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = 5, minValue=1, maxValue=15, fmx=200 )
    twistField = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Twist', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = 0, fs=.01, minValue=-1.0, maxValue=1.0, fmx=5.0, fmn=-5.0 )
    mc.button( label='Cough it up!', command='''
import maya.cmds as mc
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
hairTools.makeHair(mc.ls(sl=True, fl=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, value=True), mc.intSliderGrp("%s", q=True, v=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, value=True))
''' % (densityField, layerField, twistField))
    mc.setParent( '..' )
    mc.setParent( '..' )

    mc.frameLayout( label='Groom', labelAlign='center', borderStyle='etchedIn' )
    mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn = True)
    rand1Field = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Start', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .1, fs=.1, minValue=0, maxValue=5.0, fmx=200.0 )
    rand2Field = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Middle', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .4, fs=.1, minValue=0, maxValue=5.0, fmx=200.0 )
    rand3Field = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='End', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .6, fs=.1, minValue=0, maxValue=5.0, fmx=200.0 )
    mc.button( label='Muss it up.', command='''
import maya.cmds as mc
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
hairTools.randomizeHair(mc.ls(sl=True, fl=True), [mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, value=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, v=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, v=True)])
    ''' % (rand1Field, rand2Field, rand3Field))
    mc.setParent( '..' )
    mc.setParent( '..' )

    mc.frameLayout( label='Trim', labelAlign='center', borderStyle='etchedIn' )
    mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn = True)
    minTrimField = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Min Length', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .3, fs=.1, minValue=0.1, maxValue=1.0 )
    percentTrimField = mc.floatSliderGrp( label='Percent to trim', cw3=[80, 80, 120], field=True, value = .5, fs=.1, minValue=0.1, maxValue=1.0 )
    mc.button( label='A little off the top.', command='''
import maya.cmds as mc
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
hairTools.trimHair(mc.ls(sl=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, value=True), mc.floatSliderGrp("%s", q=True, value=True))
    ''' % (minTrimField, percentTrimField))
    mc.setParent( '..' )
    mc.setParent( '..' )

    mc.showWindow( window )

    mc.window(window, e=True, w=310, h=400)

def makeHair(firstLoop, density, layers, twist=0.0):
    firstLoop = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(firstLoop, fe=True, fv=True, tv=True), fl=True)

    # DO A LITTLE ERROR CHECKING TO SEE IF WE GOT WHAT WE NEED
    neighbor = getNeighboringEdgeloops(firstLoop)
    if len(neighbor) != len(firstLoop):
        mel.eval('warning "Selected edgeloop is not a border loop. Please select a border loop and try again."')
        return None

    # CREATE THE HULL CURVES
    if twist < 0:
        numIntermediates = round((twist*-1)/.1)-1
    else:
        numIntermediates = round(twist/.1)-1
    if numIntermediates < 0:
        numIntermediates = 0
    hullCurves = makeHullCurves(firstLoop, numIntermediates)

    twist /= numIntermediates + 1.0

    objName = firstLoop[0].split('.')[0]

    # CREATE ALL THE HAIR CURVES
    allHairCurves = []
    for i in range(layers):
        for curve in hullCurves:
            s = (i+1)/(layers*1.0)
            mc.setAttr(curve+'.scale', s, s, s, type='double3')
        allHairCurves += makeHairCurves(hullCurves, density, twist)

    # DO SOME SPRING CLEANING
    mc.delete(hullCurves)
    for i in range(len(allHairCurves)):
        curveNum = str(i+1)
        allHairCurves[i] = mc.rename(allHairCurves[i], '%s_%sCRV' % (objName, curveNum))

    if len(allHairCurves) > 0:
        hairGrp = mc.rename(mc.group(allHairCurves), objName + '_hairCurves')
    else:
        mel.eval('warning "No hair curves made. Perhaps Density value is too high."')

def makeHullCurves(firstLoop, numIntermediates=0):
    verts = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(firstLoop, fe=True, fv=True, tv=True), fl=True)

    edgeVerts = orderEdgeloopVerts(verts)
    firstVert = edgeVerts[0]
    dirVert = edgeVerts[1]

    obj = verts[0].split('.')[0]
    numObjVerts = mc.polyEvaluate(obj, vertex=True)

    numEdges = numObjVerts / len(edgeVerts)

    if numObjVerts%len(edgeVerts) != 0:
        mel.eval('warning("Number of verts in edge loops must be the same throughout mesh.")')
        return False

    usedVerts = []
    edgeCurves = []
    edgeLoops = []
    usedVertOrder = []
    for i in range(numEdges):
        # MAKE CURVES
        currentEdge = makeCurveFromVerts(edgeVerts)[0]
        if i != 0 and numIntermediates != 0:
            edgeCurves += makeIntermediateCurves(edgeCurves[-1], currentEdge, numIntermediates)
        edgeCurves.append(currentEdge)

        # KEEP TRACK OF USED VERTS
        for vert in edgeVerts:
            if vert not in usedVerts:
                usedVerts.append(vert)
        usedVertOrder.append(copy.copy(usedVerts))

        # GET NEXT LOOP
        edgeLoops.append(edgeVerts)
        neighbors = mc.ls(getNeighboringEdgeloops(edgeVerts), fl=True)
        edgeVerts = []
        for vert in neighbors:
            if vert not in usedVerts:
                edgeVerts.append(vert)
        if len(edgeVerts):
            firstVert = findCorrespondingVertInLoop(firstVert, edgeVerts)
            dirVert = findCorrespondingVertInLoop(dirVert, edgeVerts)
            edgeVerts = orderEdgeloopVerts(edgeVerts, start=firstVert, direction=dirVert)

    return edgeCurves

def makeIntermediateCurves(curve1, curve2, numIntermediates=1, close=True):
    cShape1 = mc.listRelatives(curve1, shapes=True)[0]
    cShape2 = mc.listRelatives(curve2, shapes=True)[0]

    numCV1 = mc.getAttr(cShape1+'.spans') + mc.getAttr(cShape1+'.degree')
    numCV2 = mc.getAttr(cShape2+'.spans') + mc.getAttr(cShape2+'.degree')

    if numCV1 != numCV2:
        mel.eval('warning "Number of CVs between curves are not equal. Can\'t create intermediate curves"')
        return []

    step = 1.0/(numIntermediates+1)
    allCurves = []
    for p in range(1, numIntermediates+1):
        points = []
        for i in range(mc.getAttr(cShape1+'.spans')):
            p1 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (curve1,i))
            p2 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (curve2,i))
            v = (p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1], p2[2] - p1[2])
            p3 = (p1[0]+(v[0]*step*p), p1[1]+(v[1]*step*p), p1[2]+(v[2]*step*p))
            points.append(p3)
        allCurves += makeCurveFromPoints(points, close)
        allCurves[-1] = mc.rename(allCurves[-1], 'intCurve1')
    return allCurves

def orderEdgeloopVerts(verts, start=None, direction=None):
    '''
    Orders a list of verts in an edge loop.
    Assumes the verts are actually in an edge loop,
    otherwise will freeze Maya, so be WARNED!!
    '''
    allEdgeVerts = copy.copy(verts)

    orderedVerts = []
    if not start:
        start = verts.pop(0)
    else:
        if start in verts:
            verts.remove(start)
        else:
            mel.eval('warning("given start vert is not in edge verts, using default")')
            start = verts.pop(0)
    if direction and direction in verts:
        verts.remove(direction)
    else:
        adjacentVerts = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(mc.polyListComponentConversion(start, fv=True, te=True), fe=True, tv=True),fl=True)
        for vert in adjacentVerts:
            if vert in verts:
                direction = vert
        verts.remove(direction)

    orderedVerts.append(start)
    orderedVerts.append(direction)

    while len(verts) > 1:
        adjacentVerts = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(mc.polyListComponentConversion(orderedVerts[-1], fv=True, te=True), fe=True, tv=True), fl=True)
        for vert in adjacentVerts:
            if vert in verts:
                orderedVerts.append(vert)
                verts.remove(orderedVerts[-1])

    orderedVerts.append(verts[0])
    return orderedVerts

def makeCurveFromVerts(verts, close=True):
    p = []
    for vert in verts:
        p.append(mc.pointPosition(vert))

    return makeCurveFromPoints(p, close)

def makeCurveFromPoints(p, close=True):
    curve = mc.curve(p=p, d=3)
    if close:
        curve = mc.closeCurve(curve, ps=0, rpo=1, bb=0.5, bki=0, p=0.1)
    curve = mc.rebuildCurve(curve, rpo=1, rt=0, end=1, kr=0, kcp=1, kep=1, kt=0, s=4, d=3, tol=0.000129167)

    mc.xform(curve, centerPivots=True)

    return curve

def getNeighboringEdgeloops(edgeLoop):
    '''
    Get the neighboring edge loop. 
    Takes in and returns verts, not edges
    '''
    expandedVerts = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(mc.polyListComponentConversion(edgeLoop, fv=True, te=True), fe=True, tv=True), fl=True)
    expandedEdgeVerts = mc.ls(edgeLoop, fl=True)

    for vert in expandedEdgeVerts:
        if vert in expandedVerts:
            expandedVerts.remove(vert)

    return mc.ls(expandedVerts, fl=True)

def findCorrespondingVertInLoop(vert, edgeLoop):
    '''
    Finds a vert on the edgeLoop whose edge is shared with the given vert
    '''
    nearestVerts = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(mc.polyListComponentConversion(vert, fv=True, te=True), fe=True, tv=True), fl=True)
    for vert in nearestVerts:
        if vert in edgeLoop:
            return vert

    return None

def makeHairCurves(hullCurves, d, twist = 0.0):
    '''
    Populate a hull with hair curves based on arclen of the biggest curve
    '''
    largestArclen = 0
    for curve in hullCurves:
        arclen = mc.arclen(curve)
        if arclen > largestArclen:
            largestArclen = arclen

    numCurves = largestArclen / (d * 1.0)

    allCurves = []
    for i in range(int(numCurves)):
        allCurves.append(makeHairCurve(hullCurves, i/numCurves, twist))

    return allCurves

def makeHairCurve(hullCurves, u, twist=0.0):
    '''
    Create a curve through a series of hull curves by u parameter
    '''
    p = []
    i = 0
    for hull in hullCurves:
        p.append(mc.pointPosition('%s.u[%f]' % (hull, (u+(twist*i))%1.0 ) ))
        i+=1

    curve = mc.curve(p=p, d=3)
    curve = mc.rebuildCurve(curve, rpo=1, rt=0, end=1, kr=0, kcp=1, kep=1, kt=0, s=4, d=3, tol=0.000129167)

    mc.xform(curve, centerPivots=True)

    return curve

def randomizeHair(curves, rMult = []):
    '''
    random.randomizes the cvs on a set of selected curves.
    Takes in an array that will be multiplied against the random.random value
    so that the user has more control of random.randomization along the curve.
    '''

    # FIND THE MAX NUMBER OF CVS
    longestCVCount = 0
    for curve in curves:
        numCV = mc.getAttr( curve+'.degree' ) + mc.getAttr( curve+'.spans' )
        if numCV > longestCVCount:
            longestCVCount = numCV

    # GET MULT MODIFIER VALUES FOR EACH CV
    numMult = len(rMult)-1
    numCVSplit = longestCVCount / numMult
    cvMult = []
    for i in range(longestCVCount):
        p = i/numCVSplit
        m = (i%numCVSplit)/(numCVSplit*1.0)
        try:
            dif = rMult[p+1] - rMult[p]
        except:
            dif = rMult[p]
        cvMult.append( (m*dif)+rMult[p] )

    for curve in curves:
        numCV = mc.getAttr( curve+'.degree' ) + mc.getAttr( curve+'.spans' )
        for i in range(numCV):
            rx = cvMult[i] * (random.random() - .5)
            ry = cvMult[i] * (random.random() - .5)
            rz = cvMult[i] * (random.random() - .5)
            mc.move(rx, ry, rz, '%s.cv[%i]' % (curve, i), r=True)

def trimHair(curves, min, percent):
    '''
    random.randomly trim hair curves for more variation in length
    '''
    percentOfCurves = int(len(curves) * percent)
    for i in range(percentOfCurves):
        activeCurve = curves.pop(int(random.random()*len(curves)))
        r = (random.random() * (1.0 - min)) + min
        mc.delete(mc.detachCurve('%s.u[%f]' % (activeCurve, r), ch=False, cos=True, rpo=True)[0])

def createCenterCurve():
    firstLoop = mc.ls(mc.polyListComponentConversion(fe=True, fv=True, tv=True), fl=True)

    # DO A LITTLE ERROR CHECKING TO SEE IF WE GOT WHAT WE NEED
    neighbor = getNeighboringEdgeloops(firstLoop)
    if len(neighbor) != len(firstLoop):
        mel.eval('warning "Selected edgeloop is not a border loop. Please select a border loop and try again."')
        return None

    # CREATE THE HULL CURVEs
    hullCurves = makeHullCurves(firstLoop)

    objName = firstLoop[0].split('.')[0]

    # CREATE ALL THE HAIR CURVES
    for curve in hullCurves:
        s = 0
        mc.setAttr(curve+'.scale', s, s, s, type='double3')
    hairCurve = makeHairCurve(hullCurves, .5)

    # DO SOME SPRING CLEANING
    mc.delete(hullCurves)
    hairCurve = mc.rename(hairCurve, '%s_CenterCRV' % objName)

    return hairCurve

def trimFromBeginning(inputCurves, shortestLength):
    newCurves = []
    for obj in inputCurves:
        parent = mc.listRelatives(obj, parent=True)
        r = random.random()*(1-shortestLength)
        obj = mc.rebuildCurve(obj,  ch=0, rpo=1, rt=0, end=1, kr=0, kcp=1, kep=1, kt=0, s = 10, d = 3, tol = 0)[0]
        curves = mc.detachCurve( '%s.u[%f]' % (obj, r), ch=0, cos=True, rpo=1 )
        mc.delete(curves[-1])
        mc.rebuildCurve(curves[0], ch=1, rpo=1, rt=0, end=1, kr=0, kcp=0, kep=1, kt= 0, s = 0, d = 3, tol = 0)
        curves[0] = mc.rename(curves[0], obj)
        if parent:
            curves[0] = mc.parent(curves[0], parent)[0]

        newCurves.append(curves[0])

    return newCurves

def snapBaseToScalp(curves, scalp, mult=[.7, .4, .1]):
    import cgm.lib.distance as bbDistanceLib

    for obj in curves:
        currentPos = mc.pointPosition(obj+'.cv[0]')
        newPos = bbDistanceLib.returnClosestPointOnMeshInfoFromPos(currentPos, scalp)['position']
        relPos = [newPos[0]-currentPos[0], newPos[1]-currentPos[1], newPos[2]-currentPos[2]]
        mc.move(newPos[0], newPos[1], newPos[2], obj+'.cv[0]', a=True)
        mc.move(relPos[0]*mult[0], relPos[1]*mult[0], relPos[2]*mult[0], obj+'.cv[1]', r=True)
        mc.move(relPos[0]*mult[1], relPos[1]*mult[1], relPos[2]*mult[1], obj+'.cv[2]', r=True)
        mc.move(relPos[0]*mult[2], relPos[1]*mult[2], relPos[2]*mult[2], obj+'.cv[3]', r=True)

def pushCVOutFromScalp(cvs, scalp, pushMult = 1.5):
    import cgm.lib.distance as bbDistanceLib
    sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
    for obj in cvs:
        currentPos = mc.pointPosition(obj)
        newPos = bbDistanceLib.returnClosestPointOnMeshInfoFromPos(currentPos, scalp)['position']
        relPos = [newPos[0]-currentPos[0], newPos[1]-currentPos[1], newPos[2]-currentPos[2]]
        mc.move(relPos[0]*pushMult, relPos[1]*pushMult, relPos[2]*pushMult, obj, r=True)        
    mc.select(sel)

def pushCurveOutFromScalp(curves, scalp, pushMult = 1.5):
    import cgm.lib.distance as bbDistanceLib
    sel = mc.ls(sl=True)

    for obj in curves:
        for shape in mc.listRelatives(obj,shapes=True,fullPath=True):
            cvList = (mc.ls([shape+'.cv[*]'],flatten=True))

        for cv in cvList:
            currentPos = mc.pointPosition(cv)
            newPos = bbDistanceLib.returnClosestPointOnMeshInfoFromPos(currentPos, scalp)['position']
            relPos = [newPos[0]-currentPos[0], newPos[1]-currentPos[1], newPos[2]-currentPos[2]]
            mc.move(relPos[0]*pushMult, relPos[1]*pushMult, relPos[2]*pushMult, cv, r=True)

    mc.select(sel)

def averageCV(amount=1.0):
    for cv in mc.ls(sl=True,fl=True):
        num = int(cv.split('.cv[')[-1].split(']')[0])
        baseObj = cv.split('.')[0]
        pos1 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (baseObj, num+1))
        pos2 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (baseObj, num-1))
        pos3 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (baseObj, num))
        average = [(pos1[0]+pos2[0]+pos3[0])/3, (pos1[1]+pos2[1]+pos3[1])/3, (pos1[2]+pos2[2]+pos3[2])/3]
        relAvg = [average[0]-pos3[0], average[1]-pos3[1], average[2]-pos3[2]]
        mc.move(relAvg[0]*amount, relAvg[1]*amount, relAvg[2]*amount, cv, r=True)

def createInterpolatedCurve(curve1, curve2, v):
    interpolatedCurve = mc.duplicate(curve1, rr=True, rc=True)[0]

    for shape in mc.listRelatives(curve2,shapes=True,fullPath=True):
        cvList = (mc.ls([shape+'.cv[*]'],flatten=True))

    mc.rebuildCurve(interpolatedCurve, ch=0, rpo=1, rt= 0, end = 1, kr = 0, kcp = 0, kep = 1, kt = 0, s = len(cvList)-3, d = 3, tol = 0)
    for i in range(len(cvList)):
        pos1 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (interpolatedCurve,i))
        pos2 = mc.pointPosition('%s.cv[%i]' % (curve2,i))
        newPos = ((pos2[0]-pos1[0])*v+pos1[0], (pos2[1]-pos1[1])*v+pos1[1], (pos2[2]-pos1[2])*v+pos1[2])    
        mc.move(newPos[0], newPos[1], newPos[2], '%s.cv[%i]' % (interpolatedCurve,i), a=True)

    return interpolatedCurve

def createRandomInterpolatedCurves(curves, numCurves):
    newCurves = []
    for i in range(numCurves):
        curve1, curve2 = random.sample(curves,2)
        newCurve = createInterpolatedCurve(curve1, curve2, random.uniform(.3, .7))
        newCurves.append(newCurve)

    return newCurves

'''
import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
hairTools.trimFromBeginning(mc.ls(sl=True), .2)
hairTools.createRandomInterpolatedCurves(mc.ls(sl=True), len(mc.ls(sl=True))*3)
hairTools.snapBaseToScalp(mc.ls(sl=True), scalp)
```

Upon running

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
```

I got this.

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/MacOS
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014
/Applications/Autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/scripts/AETemplates
/Applications/Autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/scripts/mentalray
/Applications/Autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/scripts/unsupported
/Applications/Autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/scripts
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/substance/scripts
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python27.zip
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python27.zip/lib-tk
/Users/brownzd/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2014-x64/prefs/scripts
/Users/brownzd/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2014-x64/scripts
/Users/brownzd/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/scripts
```

I see a whole bunch of things that say scripts but I'm not really sure what to do with it. Previously my script had been in

…Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2014-x64/scripts.

I went ahead and added my script files to

/Users/brownzd/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2014-x64/prefs/scripts

and

/Users/brownzd/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/scripts

hoping it would help but I'm still getting the same message.

I was doing some research and saw something about putting the **init**.py file into "apps" so I tried that (at least I think I did; I stuck it into username/Applications), but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll be more likely to get a good answer sooner if you [edit] your question to include at least the first three lines of that script. Also what version of Maya are you running?

Comment: I'm using Maya 2014 x64. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

The error you are receiving is because the module you downloaded isn't in a location the Python interpreter is looking

First, you need to find out where you can install it. Run the following command from the Maya script editor to get a list of directories:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
```

One of those likely ends something like this:

```
...username/maya/scripts
```

Copy the whole directory you downloaded (not just the files) into that location on your computer, and run the lines at the bottom of the script below the `'''` again.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get it to work. I did what you suggested but ran into the same problem. I updated my original question with a more detailed description of how I followed your instructions and my results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to contact the creator of the script and he was kind enough to tell me that typically the problem is that the people just include the files within the hairTools folder rather than including the entire folder. I stuck the folder in there and it worked just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more explicit in my answer when I said "Copy the directory you downloaded".... Glad you got it working anyway!

Comment: Well I really appreciate your help anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download hairTools zip from [here](https://github.com/dbokser/hairTools)
2. Extract the contents to 
   `/Applications/Autodesk/maya2015/plug-ins/hairTools`
3. Run this from the Python console in Maya: 

   `import sys
   sys.path.append( '/Applications/Autodesk/maya2015/plug-ins' )`

This will add the hairTools directory to your path.

4. To use, enter this in the Python console exactly:

   `import hairTools.hairTools as hairTools
   hairTools.hairballUI()`
5. The user interface will pop up and you may proceed to make your hair.

**EDIT: Needed to change some details about paths.  Have fully tested this in Maya 2015.**